# On a user's computer, how to retrieve a file from a network share that the user doesn't have permission to access

Tags: networking, permissions

On a user's computer, how can I retrieve a file from a network share that the user doesn't have permission to access?

I often find myself at a user's computer needing to [re]install this or that program that's exclusively on our IT share. Many times they will leave or step away or there's something going on where I can't logout, login as admin, get it and then log back in. I can't keep a copy of every file with me and accessing USB ports isn't always an option (permissions).

Windows 7/10, Active Directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, open a command prompt (perhaps elevated)

```
runas /user:_yourDomain_\_yourUsername_ cmd
```

Example:

```
runas /user:contoso\dsmith cmd
```

Then, to copy the file, you map the network drive

```
net use _newDriveLetter_: "\\_myServerName_\_myShareName_”
```

Example:

```
net use z: "\\fileserver01\InstallFiles"
```

Then copy the file you want:

change to the Z: drive

```
z:
```

Change to the directory

```
cd "ImgBurn"
```

Copy the file to the local computer

```
copy _filePath_ _destinationFolder\
```

Example:

```
copy IMgBurn_2.5.7.0.exe c:\temp\
```

Comment: Mapping the drive can be done as one step to avoid the `runas` command. The command would become `net use z: "\\fileserver01\InstallFiles" /user:contoso\dsmith`

Comment: While this answer is one way of doing what you wish, be aware that when you mount a network drive in user's desktop, you are subjecting this network share to a myriad of viruses user might have had installed since this morning, or since your AV software got updated, whatever. This approach works, but is Wrong. Capital W. Use read-only shares instead, nothing wrong with users seeing these, administrator is still required for a software piece to be installed on your domain computers... right?

Comment: Kitet, that's a good point, except the tech in the field would be the one with read-only access and the user have no access, and then the tech would still use the access method in this answer.

Presumably there would have to be a separate credential for adding install files to the network share.

If you're saying that the user always have read-only access then that's opening up the hole that we wanted closed in the first place: unlimited access to install files that may or may not need an install key, and therefore a licensing fail.